# How can we load component dynamically in kendo-tabstrip-tab?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip, kendo-ui-angular2

In angular 1, we had achieved this using following code :

```
<div kendo-tab-strip k-content-urls="[
'/app/Partial/general.html', 
'/app/Partial/employee.html',
'/app/Partial/department.html',
'/app/Partial/report.html']" k-options="tabOptions">
        <!-- tab list -->
        <ul class="print-item">
            <li class="k-state-active" data-item="general">General</li>
            <li data-item="employee">Employee</li>
            <li data-item="department">Department</li> 
            <li data-item="report">Report</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Can we implement the same in the kendo-UI-angular2? I didn't find anything in the documentation pertaining to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular2 you should create new components and reference them by adding their tag as tabstrip content.

```
<kendo-tabstrip>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Paris'" [selected]="true">
               <weather-paris></weather-paris>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Book Tickets'">
                    <tickets-paris></tickets-paris>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    </kendo-tabstrip>
```

Then you create a new component with their associated html template (or use a templateUrl property if you have an html template file). Example for weather-paris component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'weather-paris',
  template: '<div>The weather in Paris is {{degrees}} degrees.</div>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  degrees: number;
  constructor() {
    this.degrees = 15;
  }
}
```

More info on components [here](http://learnangular2.com/components/)

Comment: wouldn't this trigger ngOnit of both the components whenever the respective tab clicked

Comment: this is not dynamical way..